Is there a way to implement a native iOS-style swipe-back gesture in Compose Multiplatform?
Is there a way to implement a native iOS-style swipe-back gesture in Compose Multiplatform?
navigation-compose = { group = "org.jetbrains.androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-compose", version.ref = "compose-navigation" }



    NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = "home"
) {
    composable("home") { HomeScreen(navController) }
    composable("details/{itemId}") { backStackEntry ->
        val itemId = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("itemId")
        DetailScreen(navController, itemId)
    }
}

I am currently using androidx.navigation.compose for navigation in my project. Is there any solution for implementing an iOS-like swipe-back gesture?

Compose Multiplatform is finally supporting native swipe back for iOS apps in Compose Multiplatform 1.7.3.
https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/releases/tag/v1.7.3

